# No module named 'cv2'?

Tags: python, opencv

I use Python shell 3.6 version for OpenCV.

And I get the error "No module named 'cv2'".

I tried to do something from cmd screen, this time I get an internal-external command error.

How do I fix it?
It happened after formatting the computer.

Comment: Did you install OpenCV with the command `python -m pip install opencv-python`?

Answer (score 0):

Install opencv through cmd or terminal:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

> If this doesn't work out for you then there is a best alternative.

Go [here](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) and install anaconda in your system. It will automatically install all the required libraries for Machine Learning and Deep learning in python.

Comment: Sorry, cmd command does not work. Anaconda installed. I think I have to continue from anaconda now. Thank you